# What do open sets look like in the Alexandroff double cirlce?

Tags: general-topology, alexandroff-double-circle

I recently encountered the following topological space, called the *Alexandroff double cirlce*:

> The underlying set is $C = C_1 \cup C_2$, where $C_i$ is the circle of radius $i$ and centre $0$ in the complex plane. Basic open sets are:
>
> - $\{ z\}$ for every $z$ with $|z| = 2$, and
> - $U \cup \{ 2z : z \in U\} \setminus F$, where $U$ is open in the normal topology of $C_1$ and $F$ is a finite subset of $C_2$.

Just to make sure I understand this space, I have two questions.

1. Does $U \cup \{ 2z : z \in U\} \setminus F$ refer to all points in $U \cup \{ 2z : z \in U\}$ except those in $F$?
2. When it says $U$ is open in the normal topology of $C_1$, what does this mean? Are they just epsilon balls in the complex plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $U∪\{2z:z∈U\} \setminus F$ is all points in $U∪\{2z:z∈U\}$ except those in $F$.

The open sets of $C_1$ would be unions of open 'arcs' on the unit circle. I'm taking 'circle' to mean the set of points $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| =  1 \}$ rather than the 'disc' $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1 \}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, David. I do not know what you mean by open 'arcs'. Could you clarify?

Comment: An arc of the circle would be the points on the circumference between two angles, say theta1 and theta2.  An open arc would the interior of that arc, that is all the points on the circumference strictly between the two angles.